# $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ Question

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Consider the group $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. If $e$ is the order of the group, then $\forall a\in U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, $a^e\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. But why is this true? Why is it that there exists a divisor of $e$ such that $a^e$ is congruent to 1? For example, if there were a unit group with distinct non-identity elements $a$ and $b$, why is it not possible for $a^1=a$, $a^2=b$, $a^3=a$, and so on and so forth?

Also, does this mean that $a^{e-1}$ is the inverse of $a$, therefore all elements in the group have an inverse that is simply a power of themselves? By the way, I'm sorry if this should be obvious. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is true of any finite group. It follows from Lagrange's Theorem: if $H$ is a subgroup of the finite group $G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$. Apply the theorem to $H = \langle a\rangle$.

As for your second observation, you are correct; $a^{|G|} = 1 \Rightarrow a^{|G|-1} = a^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, so it's because the subgroup generated by $a$ must include the identity to be a valid subgroup, and so it indeed has an order? What ensures that all numbers in $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ form a cyclic subgroup?

Comment: The order of the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is the order of the element $a$ which is defined to the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = 1$. I'm not sure I understand your second question, but you don't need $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ to be cyclic.

Comment: Sorry, I know that not all $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ are cyclic; ie $n=8$.But if $a$ has an order, then $a$ generates a cyclic subgroup. What ensures that $\langle a\rangle$ exists? Like I mentioned before, if $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group of units mod $n$, is it never possible for $a^1=a$, $a^2=b$, $a^3=a$, and so on, where $a$ does not have an order? If $a\in U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, is there always a cyclic subgroup of $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ that $a$ can generate?

Comment: Yes. For any group $G$ and any $a \in G$, $\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. To see why we can't have the situation you mention, note that if $a^3 = a$, then $a^2.a = a$ so we have $a^2 = 1 \neq b$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I guess I need to get more comfortable with group theory to work out simple proofs like that. Thank you for your help!